# SSRS select parameter month and change par. first and last day of this month

Tags: reporting-services

i need to create parameter list of months and then (after select) recalculate two others paramateres in date format ([first day] and [last day]) of this month, can you please help me?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us how you created your "list of months". Is it just the month names? Or a number from 1 to 12 together with a month name? To calculate the dates of the "first day" and "last day" of a month, you will also need the year.

Comment: Thank you for your response
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 1, 1) AS FIRSTDAY, EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 1, 1)) AS LASTDAY, 'Januar' AS Month
UNION
SELECT        DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 2, 1) AS FIRSTDAY, EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 2, 1)) AS LASTDAY,'Februar' AS Month
UNION
SELECT        DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 3, 1) AS FIRSTDAY, EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 3, 1)) AS LASTDAY,'Marz' AS Month
So a have nice combobox with months in parameters and i need to set my another parameter (after select month) [firstday] to FIRSTDAY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are querying a database server to generate the list of months, although there's no need to do that. I suggest to rather create a list of months in the report and let the report calculate the month's names, so the language depends on the *Language* setting of the report (which can be the language configured in the user's browser).

[image: Month parameter]

For example, to calculate the *Label* for the *Value* `1`, use an expression like `=MonthName(1)`.

The *Parameters* `FirstDay` and `LastDay` (or just the values whenever you need them) can be calculated using these expressions:

- FirstDay: `=DateSerial(Today.Year, Parameters!Month.Value, 1)`
- LastDay: `=DateSerial(Today.Year, Parameters!Month.Value, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)`

Comment: Applied and works perfectly. Thank you very much for your advice. I did not know that this problem would be solved even easier. I owe you a beer.